# How do I add a tooltip for UIButton?

Tags: xcode, uibutton

Is there a tooltip property for a UIButton instance that will display text when the mouse hovers over the button?

Comment: How are you planning to use a mouse in iPhone? If you explain a little bit more detail what you are trying to achieve then you may get better solutions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UIButton is an iOS class.
There is no mouse.

Comment: I think he used Simulator :D

Comment: As for 2011, It is true that you don't have mouse in iOS, but now that we have Catalyst which let you run ios apps on macOS, we do have mouse.
To use mouse events we can use "addGestureRecognizer"

Answer (score 3):

As there is no mouse in IOS, there is no "mouse over" or tooltip property of UIButton.

But you could try to simulate one using event handling.

If user touches the button and holds his finger in, a text is shown.
If user touches up he likes to select the button.
If user does move outside the button and ends the touch there, the tooltip is hided.

Check UIControlEvent for UIButton, i.e. "Touch Up Inside" "Touch Drag Enter" "TOuch Drag Exit"

Answer (score 0):

That is true that you don't have mouse in iOS, but now that we have [Catalyst](https://developer.apple.com/mac-catalyst/) which let you run ios apps on macOS, we do have mouse.

For any UIView you can use :

```
addGestureRecognizer(UIHoverGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hoverEvent(_:))))
```

and do what you want in the implementation such as :

```
    @objc
func hoverEvent(_ sender: UIHoverGestureRecognizer? = nil) {
    
    switch sender?.state {
    case .began, .changed:
        myButton.isHidden = false
    case .ended, .cancelled, .failed, .possible:
        myButton.isHidden = true
    default:
        break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add a hover gesture to your tool bar:

   // hover

   let hover = UIHoverGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.hovering(_:)))
   self.toolBar?.addGestureRecognizer(hover)
2. Loop through the buttons of the toolbar and assign a UIToolTipInteraction:

   @objc func hovering(_ recognizer: UIHoverGestureRecognizer) {

   ```
    let location = recognizer.location(in: self.toolBar)

    let buttons = self.toolBar?.items ?? []

    // state

    switch recognizer.state {

        case .began, .changed:

            for button in buttons {

                let view = button.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView

                if view?.frame.contains(location) ?? false {

                    view?.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(
                        red: 33.0/255.0,
                        green: 33.0/255.0,
                        blue: 33.0/255.0,
                        alpha: 1.0)

                    let interaction = UIToolTipInteraction(defaultToolTip: button.title)

                    view?.addInteraction(interaction)

                } else {

                    view?.backgroundColor = .clear

                }

            }

            break

        case .ended:

            for button in buttons {

                let view = button.value(forKey: "view") as? UIView

                view?.backgroundColor = .clear

            }

            break

        default:
            break

    }
   ```

   }